# config.json file is missing when importing UI package to Android project with Relay plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, figma

I am attempting to import a UI package from Figma using the Relay plugin for Android studio

Whenever I do, the following files are imported for the UI package:

[image: Files imported from Figma]

After attempting to make the project after import I have the following error:

```
/Users/oli/AndroidStudioProjects/RelayTest/app/src/main/ui-packages/text_elements/config.json (No such file or directory)
```

It seems the config.json file is not being imported. Am I doing something wrong?

I am using the following version of Relay on Android Studio Flamingo:

```
    id 'com.google.relay' version '0.3.05'
```

**Update**

Also noticed I am also getting this error directly after importing the UI package:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 632: Encountered an unknown key 'menu'.
Use 'ignoreUnknownKeys = true' in 'Json {}' builder to ignore unknown keys.
JSON input: .....22/esDR31xSG-6AGleN2tOklQ.ttf"
    },
    {
      "family": .....
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonReader.fail(JsonReader.kt:333)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonReader.fail$default(JsonReader.kt:332)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeObjectIndex(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:145)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeElementIndex(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:88)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.Webfont$$serializer.deserialize(FontFetcher.kt:180)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.Webfont$$serializer.deserialize(FontFetcher.kt:180)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:63)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(AbstractDecoder.kt:41)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(AbstractDecoder.kt:63)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.CompositeDecoder$DefaultImpls.decodeSerializableElement$default(Decoding.kt:479)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.ListLikeSerializer.readElement(CollectionSerializers.kt:80)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.readElement$default(CollectionSerializers.kt:51)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:63)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(AbstractDecoder.kt:41)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(AbstractDecoder.kt:63)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.WebfontList$$serializer.deserialize(FontFetcher.kt:176)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.WebfontList$$serializer.deserialize(FontFetcher.kt:176)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.PolymorphicKt.decodeSerializableValuePolymorphic(Polymorphic.kt:63)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:85)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.FontFetcher.downloadFonts(FontFetcher.kt:225)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.fonts.FontFetcher.downloadFontAssets(FontFetcher.kt:68)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.uipackage.UIPackageManager.importAndDownloadFonts(UIPackageManager.java:95)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.uipackage.UIPackageTasks$createImportAndDownloadFontsTask$1$run$$inlined$runReadAction$1.compute(actions.kt:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:928)
    at com.google.relay.androidstudio.plugin.uipackage.UIPackageTasks$createImportAndDownloadFontsTask$1.run(UIPackageTasks.kt:229)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$5(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I have the same issue,  I opened a bug for its tracker.  
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279644042

Comment: hi @marioromanolopez, I'm getting access denied for the issue link you've provided